# Aggregate based on different nodes with equivalent date time property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to get an aggregating query in tabular format, based on date. The simplest way to describe my schema is:

```
(:A {createDate: DateTime})--(:B)--(:C {createDate: DateTime})
```

Right now, I was only doing aggregation on `:C` nodes, so aggregating was very simple:

```
MATCH ..
RETURN 
  date(c.createDate),
  count(c),
  avg(c.property),
  etc.
```

However, now that I have two independent nodes that share this property, I'm not sure how to move forward. I suppose I have to somehow unwind and collect the nodes together but I can't seem to get it to work.

**EDIT**:

I've discovered I can do something like this:

```
MATCH (a:A)--(b:B)--(c:C)
WITH CASE WHEN date(a.createDate) = date(c.createDate) THEN a ELSE {} as a
RETURN 
..
```

This works in practice, but it feels quite dodgy. Is that a better / recommended way to do this kind of operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
MATCH (a:A)--(b:B)--(c:C)
WITH COLLECT(a) AS aNodes, COLLECT(c) AS cNodes
WITH aNodes + cNodes AS totalNodes
UNWIND totalNodes AS n
RETURN date(n.createDate), count(n), avg(n.property), etc.
```